# I get this error while tying to join a file using the os path

Tags: jupyter-notebook

**filepath=os.path.join('SalesData')
filepath**

**disFile=os.listdir(filepath)
disFile**

joinFile = os.path.join(disFile, "Sales_Data_2020")

I keep getting this error:

> ---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [15], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 joinFile=os.path.join(disFile,"Sales_Data_2020")

File ~\anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py:78, in join(path, *paths)
77 def join(path, *paths):
---> 78     path = os.fspath(path)
79     if isinstance(path, bytes):
80         sep = b'\'

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what `disFile` represents in your case, this should do the trick:

```
joinFile = os.path.join("disFile", "Sales_Data_2020")
```

According to the error I guess that `disFile` on your end represents a list which won't work. Thus, you would have to select a string of that list to join it.

See also the [official docu](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)